# I cannot create a folder in my windows drive from Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, permissions, storage

I can't create a folder in my windows D Drive from Ubuntu. Is there is any solution? [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5OL0.jpg), [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtPiR.jpg)

Comment: This website is for questions about programming - this means: **Developing and writing** own computer programs - only. The site is part of the StackExchange network; your user name and password is valid for all sites in that network. Websites in the StackExchange network about **using** operating systems are: ["Unix&Linux"](https://unix.stackexchange.com), ["Ask Ubuntu"](https://askubuntu.com) or ["Super User"](https://SuperUser.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similiar problem few days ago, the solution is to not to **shutdown** windows (if you are using dual-booting) but to **restart** and choose ubuntu in grub. Because widnows is never shutdowning completely but only going to hibernate so the drive is somehow reserved by windows.

So step by step:

1. Boot up windows.
2. Press **restart** not shutdown!
3. Select ubuntu in grub.
4. You should be able to create folder.

Hope it helps. :)